# Need help with a specific distribution algorithm

Tags: algorithms

Here is the problem:

We have an ordered To-Do list with n tasks. The duration of every task is given and tasks need to be completed in order. We need to distribute the tasks to m days. Individual tasks cannot be split between days. How can we minimize the variance of the total task duration of days?

Comment: Sounds like dynamic programming.

Comment: I hadn't considered dynamic programming. Will look into that.